# React Native TextInput setState() issue

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue with React Native's this.setState() within a TextInput's onChangeText. I am trying to display the content of the TextInput in the Text tag below it. However, it displays nothing -- the setState() call never changes this.state.searchtext. I also get no errors. Thank you in advance for your help! Here is my code:

```
 export default class ShowScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        searchtext: ""
    };
}
render() {
    var thisscreen = (
        <View>
            <ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                pagingEnabled={true}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        height: totalheight,
                        justifyContent: "space-around",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        width: totalwidth,
                        backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
                    }}
                >
                    <TextInput
                        style={{ height: 80, fontSize: 20 }}
                        placeholder="placeholder"
                        value={this.state.searchtext}
                        onChangeText={searchtext =>
                            this.setState({ searchtext })
                        }
                        ref={input => {
                            this.textInput = input;
                        }}
                        returnKeyType="go"
                    />
                    <Text>{this.state.searchtext}</Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
    return thisscreen;
}
}
```

Comment: It will change this.state.searchtext ..  You should give value props to TextInput. Like `value={this.state.searchtext}`

Comment: @godsenal thank you for responding so quickly. Adding that prop just prevents me from entering anything into the TextInput. I want to be able to enter text into the TextInput, and have it be displayed in the Text tag below.

Comment: that's weird. Could you paste edited code? It might be typo error like misspelling `this.state.searchtext`

Comment: @godsenal it says the comment is too long if I paste in all the code. However, the only line I added was this: value={this.state.searchtext}

Comment: I tested it, it works well.. Could you edit your question to current code?

Comment: @godsenal I just edited it.

Answer (score 3):

In your `TextInput` add `value` prop

```
<TextInput
 style={{height: 80, fontSize: 20}}
 placeholder="placeholder"
 value={this.state.searchtext}
 onChangeText={(searchtext) => this.setState({ searchtext })}
 ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
 returnKeyType="go"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Adding the value prop prevents me from typing anything into the TextInput, as my this.state.searchtext never changes from "". I want to be able to display what I enter in the TextInput in the Text tag below it.

Comment: Technically the state should update and so should your view, where ever you want to display the updated state text.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you have used a variable to store screen code which is thisscreen. This might be preventing it from updating state.

Your render function should be like this:

```
 render () {
   return (
     <View>
        <ScrollView
         horizontal={true}
         showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
         pagingEnabled={true}
        >
             <View style={{
               flex: 1,
               height: totalheight,
               justifyContent: "space-around",
               alignItems: "center",
               width: totalwidth,
               backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
             }}>
             <TextInput
              style={{height: 80, fontSize: 20}}
              placeholder="placeholder"
              value={this.state.searchtext}
              onChangeText={(searchtext) => 
               this.setState({searchtext})}
              ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
              returnKeyType="go"
             />
            <Text>{this.state.searchtext}</Text>
         </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>);
 }
```

Comment: Hey Hobbes can you check this solution

Answer (score 0):

onChangeText={(search_text) => this.setState({searchtext:search_text})}

try this, that might do job.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Changing to this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might bug in React `onChangeText` method. You just need to replace `onChangetText` to `onChange` then It will work fine.

```
  <TextInput
            style={{height: 80, fontSize: 20}}
            placeholder="placeholder"
            onChange={(text) => this.setState({searchtext : text})}
            ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
            returnKeyType="go"
          />
```

Comment: You have forgot to assign value. replace with this line. `onChange={(searchtext) => this.setState({ searchtext : searchtext})}`

Comment: Did you declared `searchtext : ""` in state object. Because same code work in my application

Answer (score 0):

When you use setState, we provide a JSON as parameter. Please follow below code.

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: 80, fontSize: 20}}
  placeholder="placeholder"
  value={this.state.searchtext}
  onChangeText={(searchtext) => this.setState({ searchtext: searchtext })} // <-- 
  ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
 returnKeyType="go"
/>
```

Do let me know if it does not work.